# How to create a custom route in wordpress without any plugin?

Tags: routing

I need to create a custom route in Wordpress to run some $.post callback methods for which I have to use init hook method, is there any way we can simply create a route ?

Comment: If you want to make AJAX requests you should use the REST API and register an endpoint

Comment: Any examples for the rest api ?

Comment: @harshal can you be more specific about what you're trying to do - e.g. some quick code examples? Presumably you know that you can add code to do what you need into functions.php without creating a plugin?

Comment: Also be warned that if any answers you get can be turned into a plugin by putting them in a file with `<?php /** Plugin Name: Harshals Plugin */` at the top. Plugin recommendations would be offtopic here. Keep in mind these are the comments, not the answers